# Ajax post request is received as empty object

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post, laravel-4

I send an ajax post request , and get a response, but it comes up empty. Is there is some details that need to be adjusted?

The idea is to send text that is submitted with a submit button. But just for testing, I have specified the data to be sent as "url": "helllo".

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('form.ajax').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

    var submitted = $(this),
        destination = submitted.attr('action'),
        method = submitted.attr('method'),

        url_send = {
          "url": "helllo"
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: method,
            contentType : 'application/json',
            url: destination,
            data: url_send,
            success: function(response){
                console.log(response);

            },
            error: function(){
                console.log("there was an error");
            }
        });
```

The "method" (post) and "destination" is specified in the form. So "url_send" is the object which is sent. Should this be retrieved as {"url": "helllo"} on the other end, or is it nested inside an object?

In PHP with laravel,I have a controller function where the request is recieved:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
```

If $data is empty, it's returned:

```
return Response::json($data);
```

And that gives me

```
Object {  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing `data` an object, so it will be urlencoded by jQuery.

urlencoded data is not JSON, so trying to parse it as JSON will fail.

You need to actually send JSON.

```
data: JSON.stringify(url_send)
```

Comment: I have actually tried this, but the request fails and the error is shown. Is there something more I need to do on the backend?

Comment: Now I understand, it DID work, I was expecting a custom error message to be returned from php , but that seems to cause the request to fail also. However I can see the error message in the browser console, on network - response. Thanks for the explanation!